# Disable Wipe data & factory reset

Tags: android, mdm

I'm developing application that provides child protection(blocking obscene contents, apps, etc.) kind of kiosk mode. And i want to disable factory reset. I found solution using Samsung KNOX SDK (for Samsung devices only) that provide to block factory reset and even wipe data from boot menu. But using other device i'm able only block screen with `AccessibilityService` when user opens factory reset settings. Does exsist SDK or built-in abbility to disable wipe data for all devices?
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, no. If apps were allowed to disable system features that would be a problem, especially in terms of malicious software. It is probably possible on rooted devices, but I have never developed root apps so I am not sure. The knox SDK has essentially admin access on Samsung devices, which is why it can do stuff like it. Other vendors rarely have SDK's like it though

Comment: Tnx @LunarWatcher. I'm absolutely agree with that and know about `DeviceOwner` privilege. But may be i missed something, hope will never die :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=46071323) to manage your device and set `factoryResetDisabled` to `true` in the device's [Policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies). This API supports any device running Android 5.1 or above.

Under the hood the Android Management API sets the [DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET) restriction, which can only be set by a device owner or profile owner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Fred. I was used this beta `API` out of curiosity but there is unacceptable requirement for me as "Turn on a new or factory-reset device"

Comment: Hi Stanislav, the [DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET) restriction that allows disabling factory reset "can only be set by device owners and profile owners", and therefore requires a new or factory-reset device. The limited [Device Admin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) management doesn't support this feature, likely for security purpose to prevent malicious apps from taking full control of a device.

Answer (score 0):

You can set device managment through adb, then you don't need to full reset your phone. See the Sourcecode and tutorial on TestDPC for help.

Answer (score 0):

[Fred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216089/12664985) is correct, but if you want some code:

```
val devicePolicyManager = context.getSystemService(
            Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE
        ) as DevicePolicyManager

devicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(
        ComponentName(context.applicationContext, MyDeviceAdminReceiver::class.java),
        UserManager.DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET
    )
```

`MyDeviceAdminReceiver` is the class you extended `DeviceAdminReceiver` when setuping your application to be a Device Owner.